# Automatic keyframing offset?

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I'm trying to get a certain object to use another object's animation data, but offset by (for example) 10 keyframes. How can I do this?

Comment: What property (Scale, Location, Rotation...)?

Comment: Mostly location, but all if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlenderDiplom has created an Add-on called [AReWo](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/544-arewo-gui-addon-video-tutorial.html) (Animation Replicator with Offset) which does exactly what you want. They provide a Video-Tutorial of how to use it and a [Download page](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/537-arewo-gui-a-detailed-description.html) where you can find the direct link.

Another possibility is using the [Animation Nodes](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350296-Addon-Animation-Nodes&p=2735464&viewfull=1#post2735464) by Jacques Lucke.

Or you can use the [Blendgraph](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?322496-AddOn-Blendgraph-2-7-UPDATED-(on-hiatus)&p=2546404&viewfull=1#post2546404) Add-on to animate Text with a so called *Font Repeater Node*.